# Middleman not parsing source file up template chain if missing ERb tags

Tags: ruby, middleman, tilt

I'm converting a Jekyll site to Middleman. I have named my files like filename.html.md.liquid.erb for processing with those libraries in that order: ERb, then liquid, then kramdown. What I found is that if I don't have at least one erb tag in the file, the template parsing simply stops and the whole file is rendered as plain text rather than being parsed by liquid and then kramdown. Simply adding

```
<% if nil %>
<% end %>
```

at the bottom of the source document causes the whole template chain to be rendered, but I don't want to be *forced* to include these. I simply want to have the *option*.

Edit: I just discovered this also applies if *any* of the templates specified via the extensions don't actually have any processing to do. So, for instance, if I have filename.html.md.liquid.erb and I have ERb tags but no liquid tags, the ERb will render fine, but Markdown will be output as static text.

I've tagged this as tilt and middleman both just because I'm not sure where the problem might lie.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason for this is related to caching. When I remove the cache call, the templates render all the way up the chain. I also changed the cache key to use the template extension and that seems to work as well. By changing [rendering.rb:257](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/3.0-stable/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/rendering.rb#L257) to

```
template = cache.fetch("compiled_template_#{extension}".to_sym, options, body) do
    ::Tilt.new(path, 1, options) { body }
end
```

the template chain parses up the rest of the extensions even if the previous template's processing did not contain any of that templating languages tags. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/798) in Middleman as there may be a better way to solve it than this.