# Chaining multiple engines (coffeescript and jsx) using Middleman

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sprockets, middleman, tilt

Using Middleman, how can I chain multiple file extensions for processing by multiple engines?

Middleman handles CoffeeScript out of the box, and I have `gem middleman-react` in my `Gemfile` and `activate :react` in my `config.rb`.

Processing regular jsx files like `my_file.js.jsx` works fine, but I want to have a file like `my_file.js.jsx.coffee`, which isn't working.

It's parsed correctly as CoffeeScript, but is then not parsed as `jsx`.

Here's some sample output:

```
BoardRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return <tr className='row'>{this.props.intersections}</tr>;
    }
});
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991807/middleman-not-parsing-source-file-up-template-chain-if-missing-erb-tags) it looks like this kind of thing should be possible.

Comment: Try asking in `middleman-react`'s issue queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the magic jsx comment was malformed in my CoffeeScript file, so the parser was skipping it.

Make sure your CoffeeScript file starts with:

```
###* @jsx React.DOM ###
```